# Where should I place my lib tests

Tags: unit-testing, dart

Note that I have already read the [layout convention](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html).

In my `lib` directory I usually have a few libraries I could extract into their own package.  Very often the code is not complete enough or / and I want to wait for a new package until I really want to reuse the code in another project.

I would really like to place the unit-test code, examples and doc in the same directory.

Example:
let's say I have a `string-helper` library in `lib` → `lib/string-helper`.
I would like to place my tests, examples and doc in `lib/string-helper/tests`, `lib/string-helper/examples`and `lib/string-helper/doc`.

However the layout convention says that I should put them outside the lib directory.

This makes it unnecessarily hard to extract it into its own package.  (`pub serve` even went into an endless loop when I ignored this and made my own `package` symbolic link)

How do you handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only valid place for tests is the `my_package/test` directory or any subdirectory of `test`.

Comment: Even though your answer is correct, after all, that's exactly what the layout convention says, it's not very helpful.

Comment: I didn't know what to suggest. I think `lib` is the worst place for tests of all possibilities. If you can't place them in `lib` I don't think there is any reason left to not placing them into `test`. If you put them into `lib` it is built to JavaScript which increases the size (could be tree-shaken though). It is also made available to people adding the package as dependency.
I have to admit that I didn't understand your problem with extracting to their own package. You can have a directory structure in `test` mirroring the structure in `lib` (don't know if this helps)

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter and wanted to add a lot more text:

I guess my question should have been more clear: how do you avoid a "bad" layout and the unnecessary work, even though the only valid place for tests is `my_package/test`.

Apparently (and that's not related to your answer) nobody really cares, so I will accept this answer and not fight this too much.  (Even though I still think that we are following a bad convention).

Comment: I also like how for example `Go` has the tests in the same directory as the code they test but in Dart there is just no support for such a layout and it will cause you only troubles if you try.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer like: «Placing the tests in `lib/my_package/tests` and let `tests/all_tests.dart` find those tests (maybe with mirrors...) is a common practice...

Replicating the directory hierarchy in tests is a bad idea, because if you rename one of your libs the hierarchy might be out of sync...»

IMO tests should even be allowed in the same file as the code.  This should not increase the code size for JavaScript (and because of the dart2dart compile step not even for dart).